# ASP.net WebPart title icons

Tags: asp.net, web-parts

I'm creating a web part page in ASP.net i want to display icons for minimise, restore, close etc instead of the drop down menu which is currently showing.  This code adds an icon next to the minimise icon in the menu but i want to remove the menu completly and render 3 icons in the top right of each web part. Does anyone have an example how to achieve that?

```
<asp:WebPartManager ID="WebPartManager1" runat="server"  Personalization-Enabled="true" >
</asp:WebPartManager>

<asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone1" runat="server" HeaderText="zone 1">            <MinimizeVerb ImageUrl="img/os_minimise.gif"  />  
  <ZoneTemplate>   
    <asp:Label ID="lblZone1Header" runat="server"><h1>Zone 1</h1></asp:Label>
    <uc1:TestControl ID="TestControl1" runat="server"  />
  </ZoneTemplate>
</asp:WebPartZone>

<asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone2" runat="server" HeaderTexxt="zone 2">
</asp:WebPartZone>

<asp:EditorZone ID="EditorZone1" runat="server">    
  <ZoneTemplate>
    <asp:AppearanceEditorPart ID="AppearanceEditorPart1" runat="server" />
  </ZoneTemplate>
</asp:EditorZone>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Part Zone has a property WebPartVerbRenderMode set it to menu and then Set Icons for Minimize,Restore,Close verbs etc.